# ck-editor changes html codes of non-ascii characters to actual characters

Tags: html, ckeditor, non-ascii-characters

I just started using CK-editor as "Google HTML Editor" on HTML documents on my Google Drive.

I am noticing that all non-ASCII characters represented with HTML codes are being automatically shown as the actual character.

For example I use the following codes (I am putting spaces in the code, the editor is changing them to the actual character here, too!):

```
ç   as & # 231 ; 
Ç   as & # 199 ;
Ö   as & # 214 ;
```

etc.

CK editor changes these codes within the HTML source to `Ç`, `ç` and `Ö` immediately!

Is there a way to stop this?

Comment: Honestly, I loathe `CK-editor`. Our website uses it, and I try to avoid it at all costs, because of the amount of times it has screwed me by changing the DOM layout for a silly typo or even something done on purpose that the editor just doesn't like. So for our website I came up with a neat way to load an `html` file into an element on my page, and then just use Dreamweaver to edit that HTML file. Then I don't need to worry about CK editor changing my layout.